# Open video playing in ExoPlayer into external player intent

Tags: java, android

So I have an app which plays media in ExoPlayer2 but now I wanted to add a button which can open the same video in an external player.

I am actually not getting what to add in intent so help is required.

Here's the open in external button option I'm trying to add:

```
imgPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(), "video/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
            }
        });
```

Now the issue is, idk what to add in Uri.parse(), I want the currently playing video to be played in an external player.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

My Activity Class:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int i = 0;

    private TextView tvName,tvDirector,tvRelease,tvCast,tvDes,tvGenre,tvRelated;


    private RecyclerView rvDirector,rvServer,rvRelated,rvComment;

    public static RelativeLayout lPlay;

    private EpisodeAdapter episodeAdapter;
    private HomePageAdapter relatedAdapter;
    private LiveTvHomeAdapter relatedTvAdapter;

    public static LinearLayout llBottom,llBottomParent,llcomment;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private String type="",id="";

    private ImageView imgAddFav;

    public static ImageView imgBack;
    public static ImageView imgPlayer;

    private String V_URL = "";
    public static WebView webView;
    public static ProgressBar progressBar;
    private boolean isFav = false;

    private ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;

    private Button btnComment;
    private EditText etComment;
    private CommentsAdapter commentsAdapter;

    private String commentURl;
    private AdView adView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public static SimpleExoPlayer player;
    public static PlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;
    public static SubtitleView subtitleView;

    public static ImageView imgFull;
    public static ImageView imgfit;

    public static boolean isPlaying,isFullScr;
    public static View playerLayout;

    private int playerHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        llBottom=findViewById(R.id.llbottom);
        swipeRefreshLayout=findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
        imgAddFav=findViewById(R.id.add_fav);
        imgBack=findViewById(R.id.img_back);
        webView=findViewById(R.id.webView);
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        llBottomParent=findViewById(R.id.llbottomparent);
        lPlay=findViewById(R.id.play);
        rvRelated=findViewById(R.id.rv_related);
        tvRelated=findViewById(R.id.tv_related);
        shimmerFrameLayout=findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
        simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        subtitleView=findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
        playerLayout=findViewById(R.id.player_layout);
        imgFull=findViewById(R.id.img_full_scr);
        imgfit=findViewById(R.id.fit);
        rvServer=findViewById(R.id.rv_server_list);

        imgPlayer=findViewById(R.id.img_player);

        shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();

        playerHeight = lPlay.getLayoutParams().height;

        progressBar.setMax(100); // 100 maximum value for the progress value
        progressBar.setProgress(50);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        imgBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        imgPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
            }
        });

        type = getIntent().getStringExtra("vType");
        id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");


        final SharedPreferences preferences=getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (preferences.getBoolean("status",false)){
            imgAddFav.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }else {
            imgAddFav.setVisibility(GONE);
        }

        imgFull.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isFullScr){
                    isFullScr=false;
                    showSystemUI();
                    llBottomParent.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    lPlay.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, playerHeight));
                    imgfit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    hideSystemUI();
                    isFullScr=true;
                    llBottomParent.setVisibility(GONE);
                    lPlay.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
                    imgfit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            i++;
                            Runnable r = new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    i = 0;
                                }
                            };

                            if (i == 1) {
                                //Single click
                                simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
                            } else if (i == 2) {
                                //Double click
                                i = 0;
                                simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM);
                            } else if (i == 3) {
                                // Triple Click
                                i = 0;
                                simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIT);
                            }  else if (i == 4) {
                                // Fourth Click
                                i = 0;
                                simpleExoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
                            }

                        }
                    });

                }


            }
        });

        imgAddFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String url = new ApiResources().getAddFav()+"&&user_id="+preferences.getString("id","0")+"&&videos_id="+id;

                if (isFav){
                    String removeURL = new ApiResources().getRemoveFav()+"&&user_id="+preferences.getString("id","0")+"&&videos_id="+id;
                    removeFromFav(removeURL);
                }else {
                    addToFav(url);
                }
            }
        });


        if (!isNetworkAvailable()){
            new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconError(getString(R.string.no_internet));
        }

        initGetData();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                initGetData();
            }
        });
    }


    private void initGetData(){

        if (!type.equals("tv")){

            //----related rv----------
            relatedAdapter=new HomePageAdapter(this,listRelated);
            rvRelated.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            rvRelated.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvRelated.setAdapter(relatedAdapter);

            if (type.equals("tvseries")){

                rvRelated.removeAllViews();
                listRelated.clear();
                rvServer.removeAllViews();
                listDirector.clear();
                listEpisode.clear();

                episodeAdapter=new EpisodeAdapter(this,listDirector);
                rvServer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
                rvServer.setHasFixedSize(true);
                rvServer.setAdapter(episodeAdapter);
                getSeriesData(type,id);
            }else {
                rvServer.removeAllViews();
                listDirector.clear();
                rvRelated.removeAllViews();
                listRelated.clear();

                serverApater=new ServerApater(this,listDirector);
                rvServer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
                rvServer.setHasFixedSize(true);
                rvServer.setAdapter(serverApater);
                getData(type,id);

                final ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder[] viewHolder = {null};
                serverApater.setOnItemClickListener(new ServerApater.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, CommonModels obj, int position, ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder) {
                        iniMoviePlayer(obj.getStremURL(),obj.getServerType(),DetailsActivity.this);

                        serverApater.chanColor(viewHolder[0],position);
                        holder.name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                        viewHolder[0] =holder;
                    }
                });
            }

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("user",MODE_PRIVATE);
            String url = new ApiResources().getFavStatusURl()+"&&user_id="+sharedPreferences.getString("id","0")+"&&videos_id="+id;

            if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("status",false)){
                getFavStatus(url);
            }

        }else {

            llcomment.setVisibility(GONE);

            tvRelated.setText("All TV :");

            rvServer.removeAllViews();
            listDirector.clear();
            rvRelated.removeAllViews();
            listRelated.clear();

            //----related rv----------
            relatedTvAdapter=new LiveTvHomeAdapter(this,listRelated);
            rvRelated.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            rvRelated.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvRelated.setAdapter(relatedTvAdapter);

            imgAddFav.setVisibility(GONE);

            serverApater=new ServerApater(this,listDirector);
            rvServer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
            rvServer.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvServer.setAdapter(serverApater);
            getTvData(type,id);
            llBottom.setVisibility(GONE);

            final ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder[] viewHolder = {null};
            serverApater.setOnItemClickListener(new ServerApater.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, CommonModels obj, int position, ServerApater.OriginalViewHolder holder) {
                    iniMoviePlayer(obj.getStremURL(),obj.getServerType(),DetailsActivity.this);

                    serverApater.chanColor(viewHolder[0],position);
                    holder.name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                    viewHolder[0] =holder;
                }
            });


        }
    }


    private void initWeb(String s){

        if (isPlaying){
            player.release();

        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);

        webView.loadUrl(s);
        webView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        playerLayout.setVisibility(GONE);

    }

    public void iniMoviePlayer(String url,String type,Context context){

        Log.e("vTYpe :: ",type);

        if (type.equals("embed") || type.equals("vimeo") || type.equals("gdrive")){
            initWeb(url);
        }else {
            initVideoPlayer(url,context,type);
        }
    }

    public void initVideoPlayer(String url,Context context,String type){

        progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        if (player!=null){
            player.release();

        }

        webView.setVisibility(GONE);
        playerLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new
                AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);


        TrackSelector trackSelector = new
                DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

        simpleExoPlayerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new PlayerControlView.VisibilityListener() {
            @Override
            public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                Log.e("Visibil", String.valueOf(visibility));
                if (visibility==0){
                    imgBack.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    imgFull.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    imgfit.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    imgBack.setVisibility(GONE);
                    imgFull.setVisibility(GONE);
                    imgfit.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
            }
        });

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);


        MediaSource mediaSource = null;

        if (type.equals("hls")){
            mediaSource = hlsMediaSource(uri,context);


        }else if (type.equals("youtube")){
            Log.e("youtube url  :: ",url);
            extractYoutubeUrl(url,context);
        }
        else if (type.equals("rtmp")){
            mediaSource=rtmpMediaSource(uri);
        }else {
            mediaSource=mediaSource(uri);
        }

        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);

        player.addListener(new Player.DefaultEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {




                if (playWhenReady && playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) {

                    isPlaying=true;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    Log.e("STATE PLAYER:::", String.valueOf(isPlaying));

                }
                else if (playbackState==Player.STATE_READY){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    isPlaying=false;
                    Log.e("STATE PLAYER:::", String.valueOf(isPlaying));
                }
                else if (playbackState==Player.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                    isPlaying=false;
                    progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

                    Log.e("STATE PLAYER:::", String.valueOf(isPlaying));
                } else {
                    // player paused in any state
                    isPlaying=false;
                    Log.e("STATE PLAYER:::", String.valueOf(isPlaying));
                }

            }
        });


    }


    private void extractYoutubeUrl(String url,Context context) {


        new YouTubeExtractor(context) {
            @Override
            public void onExtractionComplete(SparseArray<YtFile> ytFiles, VideoMeta vMeta) {
                if (ytFiles != null) {
                    int itag = 18;
                    String downloadUrl = ytFiles.get(itag).getUrl();
                    Log.e("YOUTUBE::", String.valueOf(downloadUrl));

                    try {

                        MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSource(Uri.parse(downloadUrl));
                        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);


                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }


                }
            }
        }.extract(url, true, true);


    }


    private MediaSource rtmpMediaSource(Uri uri){

        MediaSource videoSource = null;

        RtmpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new RtmpDataSourceFactory();
        videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);

        return  videoSource;

    }


    private MediaSource hlsMediaSource(Uri uri,Context context){

        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                Util.getUserAgent(context, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/JioTV/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"), bandwidthMeter);
        MediaSource videoSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);

        return videoSource;

    }


    private MediaSource mediaSource(Uri uri){

        return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
                new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer")).
                createMediaSource(uri);

    }

    private void addToFav(String url){

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                try {

                    if (response.getString("status").equals("success")){
                        new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconSuccess(response.getString("message"));
                        isFav=true;
                        imgAddFav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outline_favorite_24);
                    }else {
                        new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconError(response.getString("message"));
                    }

                }catch (Exception e){

                }finally {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                new ToastMsg(DetailsActivity.this).toastIconError(getString(R.string.error_toast));
            }
        });
        new VolleySingleton(DetailsActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);


    }

    private void getTvData(String vtype,String vId){


        String type = "&&type="+vtype;
        String id = "&id="+vId;
        String url = new ApiResources().getDetails()+type+id;

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);

                try {
                    tvName.setText(response.getString("tv_name"));
                    tvDes.setText(response.getString("description"));
                    V_URL=response.getString("stream_url");


                    CommonModels model=new CommonModels();
                    model.setTitle("HD");
                    model.setStremURL(V_URL);
                    model.setServerType(response.getString("stream_from"));
                    listDirector.add(model);



                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("all_tv_channel");
                    for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        CommonModels models =new CommonModels();
                        models.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("poster_url"));
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("tv_name"));
                        models.setVideoType("tv");
                        models.setId(jsonObject.getString("live_tv_id"));
                        listRelated.add(models);

                    }
                    relatedTvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                    JSONArray serverArray = response.getJSONArray("additional_media_source");
                    for (int i = 0;i<serverArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=serverArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        CommonModels models=new CommonModels();
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("label"));
                        models.setStremURL(jsonObject.getString("url"));
                        models.setServerType(jsonObject.getString("source"));


                        listDirector.add(models);
                    }
                    serverApater.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }catch (Exception e){

                }finally {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        new VolleySingleton(DetailsActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    private void getSeriesData(String vtype,String vId){

        String type = "&&type="+vtype;
        String id = "&id="+vId;
        String url = new ApiResources().getDetails()+type+id;

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                try {
                    tvName.setText(response.getString("title"));
                    tvRelease.setText("Release On "+response.getString("release"));
                    tvDes.setText(response.getString("description"));

                    //----realted post---------------
                    JSONArray relatedArray = response.getJSONArray("related_tvseries");
                    for (int i = 0;i<relatedArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=relatedArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        CommonModels models=new CommonModels();
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        models.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("thumbnail_url"));
                        models.setId(jsonObject.getString("videos_id"));
                        models.setVideoType("tvseries");

                        listRelated.add(models);
                    }
                    relatedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //----episode------------
                    JSONArray mainArray = response.getJSONArray("season");


                    for (int i = 0;i<mainArray.length();i++){
                        //epList.clear();

                        JSONObject jsonObject=mainArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        CommonModels models=new CommonModels();
                        String season_name=jsonObject.getString("seasons_name");
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("seasons_name"));


                        Log.e("Season Name 1::",jsonObject.getString("seasons_name"));

                        JSONArray episodeArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("episodes");
                        List<EpiModel> epList=new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int j=0;j<episodeArray.length();j++){

                            JSONObject object =episodeArray.getJSONObject(j);

                            EpiModel model=new EpiModel();
                            model.setSeson(season_name);
                            model.setEpi(object.getString("episodes_name"));
                            model.setStreamURL(object.getString("file_url"));
                            model.setServerType(object.getString("file_type"));
                            epList.add(model);
                        }
                        models.setListEpi(epList);
                        listDirector.add(models);

                        episodeAdapter=new EpisodeAdapter(DetailsActivity.this,listDirector);
                        rvServer.setAdapter(episodeAdapter);
                        episodeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }catch (Exception e){

                }finally {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        new VolleySingleton(DetailsActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);


    }


    private void getData(String vtype,String vId){


        String type = "&&type="+vtype;
        String id = "&id="+vId;


        String url = new ApiResources().getDetails()+type+id;
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                try {
                    tvName.setText(response.getString("title"));
                    tvRelease.setText("Released On "+response.getString("release"));
                    tvDes.setText(response.getString("description"));

                    //----realted post---------------
                    JSONArray relatedArray = response.getJSONArray("related_movie");
                    for (int i = 0;i<relatedArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=relatedArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        CommonModels models=new CommonModels();
                        models.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        models.setImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("thumbnail_url"));
                        models.setId(jsonObject.getString("videos_id"));
                        models.setVideoType("movie");

                        listRelated.add(models);
                    }
                    relatedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }catch (Exception e){

                }finally {

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        new VolleySingleton(DetailsActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);


    }

}
```

Comment: `Uri.parse(url)` . url is the link to video .,.

Comment: playing video online or offline

Comment: @NikunjParadva online video

Comment: @ADM Nope, it isn't working. It has to forward the online video link being played in ExoPlayer

Comment: `it has to forward the online video link being played in ExoPlayer` whats this mean ? Can you add a sample url you are trying to play ? Also are you using any Authentication Headers when playing Video in EXO ?

Comment: @ADM please check my edit in OP, I've added my class code. User selects a video to play from home activity which gets played in ExoPlayer2 but now I added a button which should play the same current video in an external player.

Comment: You are trying to play YouTube and RTMP streams . AFAIK YouTube videos requires special Authorization . I see you are using `YouTubeExtractor` so the link you can play with intent is the `downloadUrl`. So you can pass `Uri.parse(downloadUrl)` with Intent . I think not all player supports `RTMP strems`.[See This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057080/android-how-to-send-a-rtmp-stream-address-to-an-external-videoplayer-e-g-mx-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the url of your video, use it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://Your URL"), "video/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"));
```

For pausing your Exoplayer

```
exoplayer.playWhenReady(false);
```

Comment: What if url already contain the scheme ? This code is same as question.

Comment: but not passed the Url of video